# Convert Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, converters

I am new to use Fragment in Android. I finished the viewFilpper in Activity and now Im trying to add this function as Fragment (I could only convert it to Fragment not FragmentActivity because the whole program required). But always get error. Is anybody could help me with this.
Here is the code in Activity:

```
/*
* Copyright 2012 Harri Smatt Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
* (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the
* License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law
* or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is
* distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
* KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language
* governing permissions and limitations under the License.
*/
public class BinderActivity extends Activity implements BinderAdapter
{

private static final int[] LAYOUT_IDS = { R.layout.layout1, R.layout.layout2, R.layout.layout3, R.layout.layout4 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        BinderView binder = (BinderView) findViewById(R.id.binder);
        binder.setAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View createView(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(LAYOUT_IDS[position], null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return LAYOUT_IDS.length;
    }
}
```

And here is the code in Fragment:

```
public class BoltFragment extends Fragment implements BinderAdapter{
    private static final int[] LAYOUT_IDS = { R.layout.layout1, R.layout.layout2, R.layout.layout3, R.layout.layout4 };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        container.removeAllViews();
        View boltLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bolt,
                container, false);
        // Set title bar
        ((MenuTabsActivity) getActivity())
                .setActionBarTitle("Bolt");

        BinderView binder = (BinderView) getView().findViewById(R.id.binder);
        binder.setAdapter(this);

        return boltLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public View createView(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        //CHANGE HERE LATER
        return getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(LAYOUT_IDS[position], null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return LAYOUT_IDS.length;
    }
}
```

Here is the code in BinderAdapter:

```
public interface BinderAdapter
{

public View createView(ViewGroup container, int position);

public int getCount();

}
```

How could I do with the

```
return getLayoutInflater().inflate(LAYOUT_IDS[position], null);
```

in Fragment?

because the convert is not done yet, so errors will come out from Fragment for sure.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: what is BinderAdapter? can you post the code inside it?

Comment: can you post the error as well?

Comment: What about `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have post the BinderAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your error logs, I'm going to guess that the problem is with `BinderView binder = (BinderView) getView().findViewById(R.id.binder);
        binder.setAdapter(this);`
You can't use getView() if you're still creating it, so it should be `BinderView binder = (BinderView)boltLayout.findViewById(R.id.binder);
        binder.setAdapter(this);`

But since you're really unclear what your problem is, it could also be something else in addition. Please post your stack trace with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did the same thing.

First of all Fragment supports the function onCreateView.
Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
so change createView() to something like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   return inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_IDS[position], container, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. However, createView is just a normal method in the interface public View createView(ViewGroup container, int position); , some other method will link to that. Is there any way to keep the creatView(container, position)?